# issue related to apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am facing one issue , like I have used apache POI for generating pptx powerpoint presentation so the generated ppt is opening with libra office but when i am trying to open in ms powerpoint its creating some issues like images are not displaying , which i inserted in the presentation.I am taking byte Encoded strings in the json array and i am passing it to my 
service.Could someone help me what is the problem? Thanks

### service

```
public  Response  generatePptDocument(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
                    JSONArray  jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("image");
                    String [] stringArray=new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
                    Response result=null;
                    String uniquename=null;
                    try{
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
                            stringArray[i]=(String) jsonArray.get(i);
                            byte[] picture=Base64.decodeBase64(stringArray[i].substring(22));
                            int idx = ppt.addPicture(picture, XSLFPictureData.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                            ppt.setPageSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1600, 600));
                            //creating a slide with given picture on it
                            XSLFPictureShape pic = slide.createPicture(idx);
                            String outputDirectory = propertyUtil.getProperty("output.save.uri");
                            SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
                            String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
                             uniquename = 1 + "-" + date + "." + "pptx";
                            String streamPath = outputDirectory+uniquename;
                          //creating a file object 
                            File file=new File(streamPath);
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                          //saving the changes to a file
                            ppt.write(out);
                            StringResponse  response=new StringResponse();
                            response.setUniqueName(uniquename);
                            result=Response.ok().entity(response).build();
                          }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        log.info("Error in json Object");
                        result=Response.status(304).entity("Error in json Object").build();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){
                        log.info("Error while creating PPT Document");
                        result=Response.status(304).entity("Error while generation PPT").build();
                    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are taking the arguments as binary or input stream in `JSONObject` itseems. Make Sure that you are not getting `null JSONObject` using if condition. And, you have written:

```
byte[] picture=Base64.decodeBase64(stringArray[i].substring(22));
```

You are cutting down the string at index 22 in beginning of string itself. Make sure you are reading the string in correct way. Because the binary string you are taking might miss something while `decryption` due to substring at specific index. Even if you miss single character your binary string has no meaning.